# how to run application which has .lnk extension with .bat script

Tags: batch-file

how to run application which has .lnk extension with .bat script?
(I have an application and short of that is .lnk extension and want to run it using .bat)

error is that its not running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file with .lnk extension is just a shortcut to a file.

To launch the executable that the shortcut targets to, just write the shortcut filename in the same way as you will do to run a executable file, as follows:

```
@Echo OFF
"C:\path yo tour shortcut.lnk"
Exit
```

Or also:

```
@Echo OFF
Start /Wait "" "C:\path yo tour shortcut.lnk"
Exit
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm kinda late, but for anyone coming here:

- If the shortcut is on the desktop, check whether it is on "your" desktop or on the public one - in batch you access the public one through `%public%\Desktop`
- If you want to run multiple links, use this: `start /b \your\path`
- dont forget the quotation marks if the path has spaces in it!